# How to create a custom component?

Tags: android, components, android-view

I would like to create this component as a custom component in Android:

[image: custom component composed by label and editText surrounded by a rounded border. Label is located in left above the border.]

I shall use it like:

```
<MyEditText android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            label="ART" />
```

And like the regular EditText, when focus is on, borders and label become blue, like in the image, when focus is off, label and borders become grey.

Is it possible to create a component as described above?

Comment: It is possible to create it but show your code here what you have tried

Comment: use com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout example [https://www.journaldev.com/31980/android-material-text-fields]

Comment: Thanks @pratikvekariya, thats what I wanted !!